# How to pass data from StatelessWidget to Statefulwidget?

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-widget

I am trying to pass data from StatelessWidget to StatefulWidget, but not able to do so.
Tried various option But no success yet

**Below is the code of StatelessWidget**

```
class ListFieldsForm2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => ListFieldFormBloc2(),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          final formBloc = context.bloc<ListFieldFormBloc2>();

          return Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
              inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,

              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: formBloc.submit,
                child: Icon(Icons.send),
              ),
              body: FormBlocListener<ListFieldFormBloc2, String, String>(
                onSubmitting: (context, state) {
                  //LoadingDialog.show(context);
                },
                onSuccess: (context, state) {

                  int u;

                  String copyrights;

                  String name1;

                  var parsedData = json.decode(state.successResponse);
                  List members = parsedData['members'];
                  members.forEach((member){

                    name1 = member['firstName'];
                    
                    List<String> _firstNames = [];
                    _firstNames.add(member["firstName"]);


                  });



                  MyHomePage().steps = members;
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                 
                },
                onFailure: (context, state) {


                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text(state.failureResponse)));
                },
                
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried `MyHomePage().steps = members;` and 'MyHomePage(steps: members);', still I receive null values in the StatefulWidget

How should I pass the data?

Answer (score 0):

In StatelessWidget create a callback function (which will return data that you want to pass) and pass it through constructor to another widget

Comment: I tried many things, I request you to please show me something by example

Answer (score 0):

[Mark Davids](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13615795/mark-davids) Try this:

```
Navigator.pop(context, members);
```

Get data from your push code:

```
final members = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListFieldsForm2()),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

**First Page**

```
RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Send Data'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Testing(todos: "Hello",),
                  ),
                );
           
              },
            ),
```

**Second Page**

```
class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  String todos;
  Testing({Key key, @required this.todos}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestingState createState() => _TestingState();
}

class _TestingState extends State<Testing> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child: Text(widget.todos)),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achive  have created a sample example for you using the call back function:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(HomePage());

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: SecondPage(
            callback: (value) {
              print(value);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

typedef void StringCallback(String val);

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final StringCallback callback;
  const SecondPage({Key key, this.callback}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        callback('This is a sample text');
      },
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text('press'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

just check out and let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: you have provided only one stateless widget can you provide another widget so that I can tell you what can be done. (complete Sample would be appreciated so that we can know what are you trying to achieve).